# How to use optional with a managed type

Tags: c++-cli, clr

I want to create a function where there might be an exception and return optional if that's the case.

Here is a little code sample.

```
 optional<Exception^> opt;
        if (opt)
            MessageBox::Show("Error");
```

I get the following errors:

> Error C3265   cannot declare a managed '_Value' in an unmanaged
>   'std::_Optional_destruct_base<_Ty,false>::$UnnamedClass$0x61d94762$23$'   CLR d:\visualstudio\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\optional  87
>
> Error C2848   'std::_Optional_destruct_base<_Ty,false>::_Value': a
>   managed type cannot be a member of a
>   union CLR d:\visualstudio\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\optional  87
>
> Error C3699   '&&': cannot use this indirection on type
>   '_Ty' CLR d:\visualstudio\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\optional  431 
>      Error  C3699   '&&': cannot use this indirection on type 'const
>   _Ty'  CLR d:\visualstudio\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\optional  435
>
> Error C3699   '&&': cannot use this indirection on type
>   '_Ty' CLR d:\visualstudio\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\optional  467
>
> Error C3699   '&&': cannot use this indirection on type 'const
>   _Ty'  CLR d:\visualstudio\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\optional  476

So how can I use optional? Is it possible at all in C++ CLI? What are the alternatives?

Comment: If asking about C++/CLI, consider tagging [tag:c++-cli].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of std::optional is that it's a *value type* that might not contain a value because something failed. The .Net standard way of dealing with a failure of this type is to throw an exception or to let an exception propagate out. However, it sounds like you don't want to do this, so here's the alternatives.

For a .Net reference type (declared in C# as `class`, in C++/CLI as `ref class` or `ref struct`, used in C++/CLI with the `^`), the way to deal with this is simply to return `nullptr`. Reference types are very, very rarely stored by value, and returning null is much more standard.

For a .Net value type (declared in C# as `struct`, in C++/CLI as `value class` or `value struct`, used in C++/CLI *without* the `^`), I would use [`System::Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1). Nullable is a type similar to Optional, where a value type is allowed to be null.